# MySQL Conceptualization

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with user information, table1 and table2. In each table each user only has one row, identified by a user id number inside a user_id column.
If a value is inserted or updated inside table1 for user_id 1, is it possible to have a column inside table2 conditionally updated automatically for that user?

Comment: The term you are looking for is TRIGGER. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks g01d . How is the user_id part handled within the trigger?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't written the trigger yet.

Comment: Fair enough. I’ll come back when I’ve done more research.

Comment: Also, triggers can be messy and slow, so they aren't always the right approach. Your code could just have a transaction that updates one table and then the next, but you didn't say what, where, or how you intend to use this.

Comment: Thanks! I had a quick look at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207916/difference-between-a-trigger-and-a-transaction/207929 ... I think the trigger is what I’m after.

Comment: If that value you want to materialize in the second table can be determined by the values in the first table, it shouldn't be materialized at all. Unfortunately you didn't disclose *any* details about you actual situation so it's hard to say for sure, but it is very likely you not searching for a trigger but a join, possibly in a view.

Comment: No, the value wouldn’t be in the first table. I was looking to make it conditional using CASE. I looked into joins prior to posting, didn’t look like what I needed.